# SelectOneButton to SelectOneMenu PrimeFaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a XHTML page using `SelectOneButton` which presents a list of buttons as label from A to Z (letters) horizontally and continuously without any break or new line. It is working perfectly on **computer** screen.

But if the same page on smaller screen such as **iPhone**, the `SelectOneButton` changes from horizontal to vertical. I believe it is the design from `PrimeFaces`.

I came up with two options: if the screen provides enough space for all buttons from A to Z, then the page will use `SelectOneButton`, otherwise the page will use `SelectOneMenu` (dropbox).

What approach should I use?

Thanks,
Nghia

Comment: The solution that suites your needs most. Or do you mean how to solve this?

Comment: Oh sorry for not being cleared. I'm asking should we use JSF or Java bean to perform if else logic or could we handle by CSS?

Comment: You could handle it with css, but then you'd have two components in the page, one visible and one not. If that is not a problem for you, it is the easiest way to 'solve' this

Comment: Oh thanks. Pls advice an example of usage css in this case.

Comment: Sorry, learning css in combination with media queries is beyond the scope of my support... Lots and lots examples of this and putting `display:none` in it is a no-brainer

Comment: You helped a lot. I will find examples.